# QueryDSL predicate with OR() AND() statements returns wrong result

Tags: java, sql, spring, querydsl

I'm using QueryDSL 4.2.1 in my Spring Boot project to create simple predicate based on given UUID.

PostgreSQL table looks like this:

```
+--------------------------------------+-----+---------+--------------------------------------+
|                  id                  | ... | id_base |              id_primal               |
+--------------------------------------+-----+---------+--------------------------------------+
| 10190454-8607-47ea-a970-679255daab05 | ... | null    | 817b9faa-c282-4f87-814e-ec12443e851c |
+--------------------------------------+-----+---------+--------------------------------------+
```

Code:

```
public static Predicate createPredicate(final UUID engineId) {
    return (QCar.car.base.isNull().and(QCar.car.primal.isNotNull()).and(QCar.car.primal.engine.id.eq(engineId)))
            .or(QCar.car.primal.isNull().and(QCar.car.base.isNotNull()).and(QCar.car.base.engine.id.eq(engineId)));
}

public long countPredicate() {
    // Identifier of engine connected with primal object mentioned in database
    final UUID engineId = UUID.fromString("5407fb9a-95e5-463d-9986-9b8e9a1d03b5");
    return repository.count(createPredicate(engineId));
}
```

Result should be just value 1, but it is 0 every time. If I execute only

```
QCar.car.base.isNull().and(QCar.car.primal.isNotNull()).and(QCar.car.primal.engine.id.eq(engineId))
```

it is working fine. I will have more rows of course - some with base and some with primal, so I have to take both relations in concern. There would be one or the other (one with value and another null similarly) - never two simultaneously.

Can somebody indicate and point what I'm not understanding here?

Comment: Why are you showing us two methods that are unrelated to each other? The second method is *not* calling the first method, since the method signatures don't match.

Comment: `countPredicate()` is a method in repository interface. Repository extends `QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Car>`, so I'm just calling the method which counts results based on given `Predicate`. What's wrong with that?

Comment: @Andreas - ok,thanks. My mistake. I edited post.